# Не срабатывает перехватчик события в iframe в Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, javascript-events

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

document.body.insertBefore(iframe, document.body.firstChild);

iframe.addEventListener('load', function () {

  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; //блокируем скролл исходной страницы

  var iframeDoc = this.contentWindow.document;
  iframeDoc.body.classList.add('modal');

  iframeDoc.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var  event = event || window.event,
      closeBtn = iframeDoc.getElementById('closeBtn'),
       backBtn = iframeDoc.getElementById('backUrl');

    if ((event.target == closeBtn) || (event.target == backBtn)) {
      document.body.removeChild(iframe); //По кнопке закрытия удаляем айфрейм из DOM-дерева
      document.body.removeAttribute('style'); //и разблокировываем исходную страницу
    }
  });
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. В ФФ, опере, даже в 10 IE срабатывает закрытие айфрейма по кнопке, а в chrome не срабатывает.

Comment: Причём, если раз 7-10 нажать на кнопку — сработает обработчик. В консоли никаких ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась перевешиванием обработчиков клика на сами элементы.

```
var iframeDoc = this.contentWindow.document,
     closeBtn = iframeDoc.getElementById('closeBtn'),
      backBtn = iframeDoc.getElementById('backUrl');

  iframeDoc.body.classList.add('modal');

  closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
   backBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
});

function closeModal() {
  document.body.removeChild(iframe); //По кнопке закрытия удаляем айфрейм из DOM-дерева
  document.body.removeAttribute('style'); //и разблокировываем исходную страницу
}
```